# CacheDataSource vs SimpleCache in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am very confused with ExoPlayer and their documentation. Can anyone please explain me for what purpose and when should we use CacheDataSource and SimpleCache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CacheDataSource` and `SimpleCache` fulfill two different purposes. If you take a look at their class prototype you will see that `CacheDataSource implements DataSource` and `SimpleCache implements Cache`. When you need to cache your downloaded videos you have to use `CacheDataSource` as your `DataSource.Factory` to prepare your media playback:

```
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "AppName"));
dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(VideoCacheSingleton.getInstance(), dataSourceFactory);
```

And then use `dataSourceFactory` to create a `MediaSource`:

```
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(mediaUri);
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayerInstance = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
exoPlayerInstance.prepare(mediaSource);
```

While `SimpleCache` offers you a cache implementation that maintains an in-memory representation. As you can see in the first code block a CacheDataSourceFactory constructor needs a `Cache` instance to work with. You can either declare your own caching mechanism or use the default `SimpleCache` class that ExoPlayer provides you. If you need to use the default implementation you should keep this in mind:

> Only one instance of SimpleCache is allowed for a given directory at a given time

As per the [documentation](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/cache/SimpleCache.html). So in order to use a single instance of `SimpleCache` for a folder we use singleton declaration pattern:

```
public class VideoCacheSingleton {
    private static final int MAX_VIDEO_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 200 * 1024 * 1024;  // 200MB

    private static Cache sInstance;

    public static Cache getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance != null) return sInstance;
        else return sInstance = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "video"), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(MAX_VIDEO_CACHE_SIZE_IN_BYTES), new ExoDatabaseProvider(context)));
    }
}
```

### TL; DR

We use `CacheDataSource` to prepare a caching media playback and `SimpleCache` to build its `DataSource.Factory` instance.

Comment: whats different between DataSource.Factory and DataSource?

Comment: `Factory` classes or interfaces as the name represents does the instance creation job for you in an easier way, you pass your data to the factory class and the class handles instance creation whenever needed. In this case you build a `CacheDataSourceFactory` instance and pass it up to construct a `MediaSource`. The `ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory` calls [`createDataSource()`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DataSource.Factory.html#createDataSource--) method on your `DataSource.Factory` instance to create a `DataSource` instance.

Comment: @CoffeeJunkie As you can see in my second code block I have used a `mediaUri` to instantiate a `MediaSource` object. Use `Uri.parse(videoUrl)` to convert your url to a uri.

Comment: Oh ok but it doesn't work with the latest version, can you check my question and give me an alternative please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595132/android-kotlin-how-to-use-exoplayer-simplecache-as-of-today @Sdghasemi

Comment: To can I cache list of videos?