# Android Kotlin - How to use ExoPlayer SimpleCache as of today

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So far I found only deprecated stuff:

```
val evictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor((100 * 1024 * 1024).toLong())
val databaseProvider: DatabaseProvider = ExoDatabaseProvider(context)

val simpleCache = SimpleCache(File(context.cacheDir, "media"), evictor, databaseProvider)

val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
    simpleCache?.let {
        CacheDataSourceFactory(
            context,
            100 * 1024 * 1024, 10 * 1024 * 1024, fileUrl, it
        )
    }
).createMediaSource(fileUrl)

player.prepare(mediaSource)
```

`ExoDatabaseProvider` is deprecated and `CacheDataSourceFactory` is unresolved reference

Answer (score 1):

Use `CacheDataSource.Factory()` instead of `CacheDataSourceFactory` and `StandaloneDatabaseProvider` instead of `ExoDatabaseProvider`.

Comment: No video is shown this way

Comment: @CoffeeJunkie all videos are old. I reached this question after going through 5 deprecation alternatives